# Кнопка увеличения масштаба на сайте

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Есть сайт, на который нужно добавить кнопку, при нажатии на которую имитировалось бы нажатие CTRL + NUM'+', до 120% от начального размера. Возможно ли сделать это и какими способами? (Я не совсем знаю, к какой из меток относится данный вопрос, так как имею мало представления о web-e)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <style>
        .zoom {
            zoom: 1.2;
            -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
            -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="zoom">Zoom</button>

    <script>
        document.querySelector('#zoom').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            document.body.className += ' zoom';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```